# How to initialize a set of variable for storing data in a loop in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to save information provided by user by initializing the variables before the actual code. User is providing input through EntryBoxes in a GUI developed using tkinter.

I would like to know if I can auto initialize the variables instead of doing it manually which I did in the variable self.MainPowerTransformer.

I would also like to know if there is a way of saving the variables directly in pandas dataframe form the entry box.

The whole code is as shown below

```
from tkinter import NW
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,filedialog,simpledialog,messagebox
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana",12)

class WindFarmInput(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"Wind Farm Simulation Input")

        self.MainPowerTransformer = {
                "Snom_ONAN_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Snom_ONAF1_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Snom_ONAF2_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Z1_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "XR_Ratio_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "VHV_1" :  tk.DoubleVar(),
                "VMV_1" :  tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Tap_exist_1" : tk.StringVar(),
                "Num_Taps_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Min_Tap_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Max_Tap_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "NLL_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "FLL_1" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Snom_ONAN_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Snom_ONAF1_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Snom_ONAF2_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Z1_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "XR_Ratio_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "VHV_2" :  tk.DoubleVar(),
                "VMV_2" :  tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Tap_exist_2" : tk.StringVar(),
                "Num_Taps_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Min_Tap_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "Max_Tap_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "NLL_2" : tk.DoubleVar(),
                "FLL_2" : tk.DoubleVar()
                }

        self.from_bus = {}
        self.to_bus = {}

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.wind_turb_num = {}

        self.WT_connection_info = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Bus Name','WT Model','P(MW)','Qind(MVAR)','Qcap(MVAR)','VLV(kV)'])
        self.PadMount_trafo_WT_connection = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Bus Name','WT Model','S(MVA)','VMV(kV)','VLV(kV)','Z(pu)','X\R','NLL(kVAR)','FLL(kVAR)'])

        self.frames = {}

        self.MPT_Tap = {}

        self.MainPowerTrafo_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Snom_ONAN','Snom_ONAF1','Snom_ONAF2','Z1','XR_Ratio','VHV','VMV','Tap_exist','Min_Tap',
                                                         'Max_Tap','NLL','FLL'])

        for F in (StartPage,MainPowerTransformerEntry):
            frame = F(container,self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nsew")


        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page",font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self,text="Next", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(MainPowerTransformerEntry))
        button.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Quit", command=lambda:controller.destroy)
        button1.pack()

class MainPowerTransformerEntry(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller=controller

        top_frame = tk.Frame(self) 
        top_frame.pack()

        middle_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        middle_frame.pack()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(middle_frame,width=700,height=330,borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)
#        self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=4,sticky="news")

        scrollbarx = tk.Scrollbar(middle_frame,orient="horizontal",command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
        scrollbarx.pack(side="bottom",fill="x")
#        scrollbarx.pack(row=3,column=1,sticky='ew')

        frame_buttons = tk.Frame(self.canvas,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_buttons, anchor='nw')

        frame_buttons.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        label = tk.Label(top_frame, text="Main Power Transformer Data",font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=1,column=2,columnspan=6)

        button1 = ttk.Button(top_frame,text="Back",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage)) 
        button1.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2) 

        button2 = ttk.Button(top_frame,text="Enter Data", command=lambda:self.enter_data(controller,frame_buttons))
        button2.grid(row=2,column=3,columnspan=2) 

        button3 = ttk.Button(top_frame,text="Next", command=lambda:[self.save_data(controller),self.controller.show_frame(MainPowerTransformerEntry)])
        button3.grid(row=2,column=5,columnspan=2)

    def enter_data(self,controller,frame_buttons):

        MPT_NUM = simpledialog.askinteger("Input Main Power Transformer Number","Enter the total number of main power transformer")
        self.MainPowerTransformerNumber = MPT_NUM

        MPT_Num = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="MPT Number",font=LARGE_FONT)
        MPT_Num.grid(row=1, column=1,columnspan=2)

        Snom = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Snom(ONAN) [MVA]",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=120)
        Snom.grid(row=1, column=3,columnspan=2)

        Snom1 = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Snom(ONAF1) [MVA]",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=120)
        Snom1.grid(row=1, column=5,columnspan=2)

        Snom2 = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Snom(ONAF2) [MVA]",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=120)
        Snom2.grid(row=1, column=7,columnspan=2)

        Z1 = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Z1 (%)",font=LARGE_FONT)
        Z1.grid(row=1, column=9,columnspan=1)

        XR_Ratio = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="X/R",font=LARGE_FONT)
        XR_Ratio.grid(row=1, column=10,columnspan=1)

        VHV = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="High Voltage (kV)",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=120)
        VHV.grid(row=1, column=11,columnspan=2)

        VMV = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Medium Voltage (kV)",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=150)
        VMV.grid(row=1, column=13,columnspan=2)

        Tap_changer = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Tap Changer",font=LARGE_FONT)
        Tap_changer.grid(row=1, column=15,columnspan=2)

        Min_Tap = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Minimum Tap Changer (%)",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=120)
        Min_Tap.grid(row=1, column=17,columnspan=2)

        Max_Tap = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Maximum Tap Changer (%)",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=120)
        Max_Tap.grid(row=1, column=19,columnspan=2)

        NLL = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="No Load Losses (MW)",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=120)
        NLL.grid(row=1, column=21,columnspan=2)

        FLL = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="Full Load Losses (MW)",font=LARGE_FONT,wraplength=120)
        FLL.grid(row=1, column=23,columnspan=2)

        list_Min_Tap = []
        list_Max_Tap = []

        for i in range(MPT_NUM):

            MPT_label = tk.Label(frame_buttons, text="MPT Num {}: ".format(i+1))
            MPT_label.grid(row=i+2, column=1,columnspan=2)

            S_ONAN_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Snom_ONAN_"+str(i+1)],width=10 )
            S_ONAN_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=3,columnspan=2)

            S_ONAF1_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Snom_ONAF1_"+str(i+1)],width=10)
            S_ONAF1_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=5,columnspan=2)

            S_ONAF2_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Snom_ONAF2_"+str(i+1)],width=10)
            S_ONAF2_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=7,columnspan=2)

            Z1_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Z1_"+str(i+1)],width=8)
            Z1_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=9,columnspan=1)

            XR_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["XR_Ratio_"+str(i+1)],width=8)
            XR_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=10,columnspan=1)

            VHV_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["VHV_"+str(i+1)],width=10)
            VHV_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=11,columnspan=2)

            VMV_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["VMV_"+str(i+1)],width=10)
            VMV_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=13,columnspan=2)

            Tap_Combo = ttk.Combobox(frame_buttons,values=['Yes','No'],height=2,width=6)
            Tap_Combo.grid(row=i+2, column=15,columnspan=2)
            self.controller.MPT_Tap[i] = Tap_Combo
            Tap_Combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, i=i:self.tap_change_selection(event,i,list_Min_Tap,list_Max_Tap))

            Min_Tap_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Min_Tap_"+str(i+1)],width=10)
            Min_Tap_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=17,columnspan=2)
            list_Min_Tap.append(Min_Tap_entry)

            Max_Tap_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Max_Tap_"+str(i+1)],width=10)
            Max_Tap_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=19,columnspan=2)
            list_Max_Tap.append(Max_Tap_entry)

            NLL_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons,textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["NLL_"+str(i+1)],width=10)
            NLL_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=21,columnspan=2)

            FLL_entry = tk.Entry(frame_buttons,textvariable=self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["FLL_"+str(i+1)],width=10)
            FLL_entry.grid(row=i+2, column=23,columnspan=2)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def tap_change_selection(self,event,i,list_Min_Tap,list_Max_Tap):
        idx = self.controller.MPT_Tap[i].current()
        print(idx)   # 1 corresponds to No and 0 corresponds to Yes based on ordering in combobox
        if idx > 0:   # Implies No Tap Changer
            self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Min_Tap_"+str(i+1)].set(0)
            list_Min_Tap[i].config(state='disabled')
            self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Max_Tap_"+str(i+1)].set(0)
            list_Max_Tap[i].config(state='disabled')
            print('disabled')
        elif idx == 0:
            list_Min_Tap[i].config(state='normal')
            list_Max_Tap[i].config(state='normal')
            print('normal')
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Incorrect Enter for Tap Changer")

    def save_data(self,controller):

        MPT_NUM = self.MainPowerTransformerNumber

        for i in range(MPT_NUM):

            self.controller.MainPowerTrafo_data.loc[i] = [self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Snom_ONAN_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Snom_ONAF1_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Snom_ONAF2_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Z1_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["XR_Ratio_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["VHV_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["VMV_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MPT_Tap[i].current(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Min_Tap_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["Max_Tap_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["NLL_"+str(i+1)].get(),
                                              self.controller.MainPowerTransformer["FLL_"+str(i+1)].get()
                                              ]

        print(self.controller.MainPowerTrafo_data)
        full_path = r'C:\GUI App 2\MPTData.csv'
        export_csv = self.controller.MainPowerTrafo_data.to_csv (full_path, index = None, header=True)


app = WindFarmInput()
app.geometry("700x400") 
#WindFarmInput().pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does not work is not a good error description. Please tell us what result you expect and what you get. And please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies about my previous code @figbeam. I have provided an example of the problem I am facing. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments @figbeam. It gave me an idea and I solved the issue with the following code

```
self.MainPowerTransformer  = dict()

        Param_list = []
        MPT_list_entries = ["Snom_ONAN_","Snom_ONAF1_","Snom_ONAF2_","Z1_","XR_Ratio_",
                              "VHV_","VMV_","Tap_exist_","Num_Taps_","Min_Tap_",
                              "Max_Tap_","NLL_","FLL_"]

        for i in range(300):
            for item in MPT_list_entries:
                Param_list.extend([item+str(i+1)])

        for field in MPT_list_entries:
            self.MainPowerTransformer[field] = tk.DoubleVar()
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a lot of code. I'm not going to try and understand it all, 
but here are some thoughts.

When you use DoubleVar() as textvariable for an Entry it will 
return an error if you input anything but a float. You might 
want to use a StringVar() and then validate the input.

With a list of column names you can construct a dict with a for-loop.

```
MainPowerTransformer = dict()
field_list = ["Snom_ONAN_1", "Snom_ONAF1_1", "Snom_ONAF2_1", "etc."]

for field in field_list:
    MainPowerTransformer[field] = StringVar()
    MainPowerTransformer[field].set('0.0')     # Set default value
```

If you want to, you can get values directly from the entrys with:

```
S_ONAN_entry.get()
```

so you won't have to mess around with different DoubleVar and StringVar.

Put that in a loop over column names and collect them all. You could 
probably use that loop to saving the data to pandas dataframe. But I 
haven't worked with pandas so you'll have to solve that yourself.

Hope this can be of help.